# selenium 3.4.0 / timeouts() implicitlyWait

Tags: java, selenium

I "move" my application from selenium 3.0.1 to 3.4.0    , now I getting this 
exception when i try to to set a implicitlyWait

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

I am getting following exception

```
the exception is org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: setTimeouts

at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:150)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:115)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:45)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:164)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:637)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteWebDriverOptions$RemoteTimeouts.implicitlyWait(RemoteWebDriver.java:868)
at test.com.gmv.esaccsop.testCases.CCSTest.<init>(CCSTest.java:76)
at test.com.gmv.esaccsop.selen.TC_CAA.caaTests(TC_CAA.java:78)
at test.com.gmv.esaccsop.selen.TC_CAA.CAA_001(TC_CAA.java:59)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:69)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:48)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:292)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
```

I have create a simple program , I´m getting the same error org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: setTimeouts

, don´t understand this ..

```
package test.com.gmv.esaccsop.selen;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class test2 {

    @Test
    public void openyahooTest() {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "c:/geckodriver/18-64/geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        System.out.println("after Init the driver");

        driver.get("http://localhost:8080/web/guest");
        System.out.println("after get localhost ");


        try
        {
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
        catch (org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
        System.out.println("after wait  ");
        WebElement title = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//title"));


    System.out.println("*" + title.getAttribute("text") + "*");

    System.out.println("********************************************************");

    driver.quit();

}
```

}

I´m getting the same error

```
after Init the driver
after get localhost 
ago 03, 2017 10:54:00 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorCodes toStatus
INFO: HTTP Status: '404' -> incorrect JSON status mapping for 'unknown error' (500 expected)
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: setTimeouts
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'PCAADR', ip: '172.19.13.14', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{rotatable=false, raisesAccessibilityExceptions=false, appBuildId=20160604131506, version=47.0, platform=XP, proxy=Proxy(), command_id=1.0, specificationLevel=0.0, acceptSslCerts=false, browserVersion=47.0, platformVersion=6.1, XULappId={ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}, browserName=Firefox, takesScreenshot=true, takesElementScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=Windows_NT, device=desktop}]
Session ID: f4eac62c-021a-4227-b050-9b82e2c5e3fa
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:150)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:115)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:45)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:164)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:637)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteWebDriverOptions$RemoteTimeouts.implicitlyWait(RemoteWebDriver.java:868)
    at test.com.gmv.esaccsop.selen.test2.openyahooTest(test2.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:69)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:48)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:292)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: Can you show the code also?

Comment: Look at these lines of code: `at test.com.gmv.esaccsop.testCases.CCSTest.<init>(CCSTest.java:76)
at test.com.gmv.esaccsop.selen.TC_CAA.caaTests(TC_CAA.java:78)
at test.com.gmv.esaccsop.selen.TC_CAA.CAA_001(TC_CAA.java:59)` Factually, **implicitlyWait** is defined in `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver` where as `TimeUnit.SECONDS` is only defined in `java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit`. I guess you missed the `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver` in one of the mentioned files. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue. fixed in `0.18.0` geckodriver version.

Solution: Upgrade to **latest** geckodriver and Firefox version.

Reference:

1. https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4529

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line -
 **driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);**
Then it should work fine.

For the latest selenium driver we don't need to specify the timeouts

Comment: Can you please give the source/documentation for this info? Didn't find anything related. Thanks